# Delete ArrayList from index i to i+3

Tags: java, arraylist

Sorry if this question is too easy or has been asked before, I'm new to programming, I have an ArrayList called `ar` declared as ArrayList `ar = new ArrayList();`

And I have the following code:

```
String delnr = "";
delnr = cin.nextLine();

if(ar.contains(delnr))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ar.get(i).equals(delnr))
        {
            ar.remove(i);

            //Here I want to remove i+1 i+2 and i+3 as well.
        }
    }
}
```

Any logical attempt I try will give me the `IndexOutOfBounds` error.

My ArrayList is of type `[dd1, x, y, z, dd2, x, y, z, dd3, x, y, z, ...]`

`delnr` can only be a `dd1` or `dd2`, etc..

So basically if my `delnr` is `dd2` I want to remove `dd2` and the `x`, `y` and `z` that come after, my new list should look like:

```
[dd1, x, y, z, dd3, x, y, z, ...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing to understand when you remove element using an index is that the `List` shrinks each time i.e. you just need to call remove again to delete the next element because the next element has taken the place of the last removed element.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("c", "b", "a", "d", "e", "j", "k"));
        System.out.println("Original list: ");
        System.out.println(list);

        // Let's say we are searching `a`
        int index = list.indexOf("a");
        if (index != -1 && ((index + 3) < list.size())) {
            // Remove element at index, index + 1, index + 2 and index +3
            list.remove(index);
            list.remove(index);
            list.remove(index);
            list.remove(index);
        }

        System.out.println("Updated list: ");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original list: 
[c, b, a, d, e, j, k]
Updated list: 
[c, b, k]
```

You can simplify the code given above by putting the repeated code inside a loop as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("c", "b", "a", "d", "e", "j", "k"));
        System.out.println("Original list: ");
        System.out.println(list);

        // Let's say we are searching `a`
        int index = list.indexOf("a");
        if (index != -1 && ((index + 3) < list.size())) {
            // Remove element at index, index + 1, index + 2 and index +3
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                list.remove(index);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Updated list: ");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original list: 
[c, b, a, d, e, j, k]
Updated list: 
[c, b, k]
```

**Notes:**

1. When the element is not found [List::indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) returns `-1`.
2. It's also important to check `(index + 3) < list.size()` to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. For example, let's say `a` was found at index `2` and there was only one element after that i.e. the list had only `4` elements in all. In that case, trying to access ([get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) or [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int))) an element from index `4` or `5` would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Could you please explain why do we check if `index != -1 && ((index + 3) < list.size())` I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: When the element is not found it returns `-1`. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) to learn more about it. I've also used `(index + 3) < list.size()` to avoid [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html). Let's say `a` is found at index `2` and there are only one element after that i.e. the list has only 4 elements in all. In that case, trying to access (get or remove) an element from index `4` or `5` will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to incorporate this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `removeRange`.  Just do it like this.  This works because the `subList` is an immutable view of the original list.  So changing the `subList` changes the original list.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,10,20,30,40,4,5,6,7));
System.out.println(list);
list.removeAll(list.subList(3,7));
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 40, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

In your case it would be something like

```
List<Integer> list = 
    new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 40, 4, 5, 6, 7));
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i) == 10) {
        list.removeAll(list.subList(i, i + 4));
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: How can I use this to delete my dd + the 3 elements after it? I am not looking to delete  some specific elements at *certain* indexes such as between 3 and 7, I want to delete the element that matches the `delnr` string of mine and the 3 other elements that come after it regardless of the position of dd that can be either 0 or 4 or 8 and so on..
If my `delnr` is "dd3" then my `dd3` from the ArrayList is on the position 8, so I guess subList(8, 12) will do the trick but then again my `dd3` can also be on other positions such as 0 or 4 or 12.

Comment: Did you try it?  It deletes items starting at i thru i + 4 (exclusive of i + 4).  Did you notice the example I provided?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the comment before I updated the page to notice you also added an "in your case" code, thank you